# What are the major new 'core' features of MS SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server

I'm looking mainly at things like new SQL syntax, new kinds of locking, new capabilities etc. Not so much in the surrounding services like data warehousing and reports...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check the whitepaper on the website? 
 [SQL Server 2008 Overview.](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/overview.aspx)

I cannot recall off the top of my head, but it atleast has a nice database to object linking functionality. They have geospatial types too, if you need to use those.

Answer (score 4):

There's a great article on the new T-SQL features [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721270.aspx) (by SQL guru Itzik Ben-Gan). It covers

- Declaring and initializing variables

  Compound assignment operators

  Table value constructor support through the VALUES clause

  Enhancements to the CONVERT function

  New date and time data types and functions

  Large UDTs (GEOMETRY and GEOGRAPHY)

  The HIERARCHYID data type

  Table types and table-valued parameters

  The MERGE statement, grouping sets enhancements

  DDL trigger enhancements

  Sparse columns

  Filtered indexes

  Large CLR user-defined aggregates

  Multi-input CLR user-defined aggregates

  The ORDER option for CLR table-valued functions

  Object dependencies

  Change data capture

  Collation alignment with Microsoft® Windows®

  Deprecation

Answer (score 3):

Filestream blob storage is the biggest bonus to me

Answer (score 1):

- New separate types for Date and Time, instead of just Datetime
- New geographic types for lattitude/longitude
- Change Data Capture is pretty neat if you're doing anything where auditing is important
- Configuration Servers, for maintaining multiple databases.

That's what caught my attention at the Heroes Happen Here launch back in April.

Answer (score 0):

HotAdd CPU. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964703.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[white paper on SQL Server 2008](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/9/d/69d1fea7-5b42-437a-b3ba-a4ad13e34ef6/SQL2008_ProductOverview.docx)

This should cover most of the new features. I noticed the new date time data types and new security features.

Answer (score 0):

Page compressiong sounds really nice to me. Haven't used it yet, though.

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/linchi_shea/archive/2008/05/11/sql-server-2008-page-compression-compression-ratios-from-real-world-databases.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Sparse indexing for those with lots of NULLs. Also the DATETIME2 data type that a lot of people have been waiting for 0001-01-01 through 9999-12-31.